# echo high > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_dpm_force_performance_level Permission denied?

Tags: bash, permissions, root, radeon

I am trying to follow this tutorial: https://gist.github.com/Francesco149/0302fbb5e056f3339ae17d3c13257929

- The first step is to run `sudo su` to switch to root. Done that.
- The second step is to run

  ```
  echo high > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_dpm_force_performance_level
  ```
- So I ran it, and here's what I got:

  ```
  bash: /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_dpm_force_performance_level: Permission denied
  ```

**Permission denied?!** How is that and I am the root user? How is it possible?

I have no idea of the inputs you would need from me, so please tell me and I will reply to you asap.

**EDIT**

Here is the output of
`echo high | sudo tee /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_dpm_force_performance_leve‌​l` (running as `root`):

```
tee: /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_dpm_force_performance_leve‌​l: Permission denied 
high
```

[image: output of echo high | sudo tee /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_dpm_force_performance_leve‌​l]

Comment: Did you try `echo high | sudo tee /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_dpm_force_performance_level` instead? This should not be different, but who knows…

Comment: [Getting “permission denied” when trying to append text onto a file using sudo](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/382946/getting-permission-denied-when-trying-to-append-text-onto-a-file-using-sudo/382947#382947)

Comment: @Ravexina Actually OP **did** `sudo su` before executing the command.

Comment: Then the entry might be protected, even if you write something there in will be overwritten by Kernel.

Comment: @dessert with `sudo tee` I get this: `tee: /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_dpm_force_performance_leve‌​l: Permission denied high`

Comment: Please [add](https://askubuntu.com/posts/949175/edit) this to your question. Does it really read “Permission denied high”?

Comment: @dessert I added what you requested.

Comment: @Rinzwind It's there. I checked right now.

Comment: next one: when root... don't use sudo :) and I have no idea on why the permissions error. :P It works for me on "backlight" (I have no power_dpm* to test)

Answer (score 2):

> In: /sys/class/drm/cardX/device

```
$ cat power_dpm_force_performance_level
auto

$ echo manual > power_dpm_force_performance_level

$ cat power_dpm_force_performance_level 
manual
```

---

```
$ cat power_dpm_state 
balanced

$ echo performance > power_dpm_state 

$ cat power_dpm_state 
performance
```

Comment: Permission denied. That's my problem.

Answer (score 1):

OP probably already figured it out (hopefully), but for anyone else with this problem:

Check if the card is enabled/powered on.

On my laptop I got that error when my gpu wasn't being used. When I for example launched a game, it turned on and I could change the performance level.